# I try to generate random (3 numbers) numbers with the php code, but when I try to return the value it doesn't work

Tags: php, function, recursion, return

Here is the php script of mine:
When I try to return value to $total and echo function generate_random_3 afterwards, in some cases it doesn't generate any number, please help

```
<?php
    function generate_random_3(){

        for($x=0; $x<3; $x++){
            $random[] = rand(1, 9);
        }
        list($first, $second, $third) = $random;

        if($first!=$second AND $first!=$third AND $second!=$third AND $first!=0){
            $total = $first.$second.$third;
            return $total;
            }else{
            generate_random_3();
            }
    }
    echo generate_random_3();
?>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant piece of code, what it should return and what it actually does return.

Comment: you miss a `return` before your repeat-call of `generate_random_3()` in the else. It returns something, but your callee function needs to return that value

Answer (score 1):

```
function generate_random_3() {
  return rand(100,999);
}

echo generate_random_3();
```

Comment: better to use mt_rand() instead of rand()

Answer (score 0):

either way....

```
$number1 = rand(0,365);
$number2 = rand(0,365);
$number3 = rand(0,365);


echo $number1 . " " . $number2 . " " . $number3;
```